# Should I break down my long list into several pages?

Tags: seo

I have a media outlet that is focused on entertainment like games and movies. We write a lot of long lists like 50 best 2021 games and such. A question that I have is that should I have one long page consisting of all of 50 games or use a split post and break them down to say, 5 pages with 10 games on each?
Also if we decided that the Split Post ones are better, does all of my posts will be crawled or just the first page?

I'll add some examples below:

This is a very long page which will be heavy but google crawler will read all content in one page:
https://uk.pcmag.com/gallery/131485/the-best-pc-games-for-2021

This is a slide show which will show one game at a time:
https://kotaku.com/the-best-video-games-of-2021-so-far-1847467401/slides/4

And finally, this is the Split Post one I've been talking about: https://www.gamesradar.com/best-pc-games/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*FYI: This answer is opinion based due to the nature of the question which will likely get closed (see our [guidelines](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)). However, I think it's constructive and that you're thinking about SEO the right way, so I'm answering anyway.*

---

### Yes, But Let's Be Strategic About It

I would employ taxonomy here and create custom post types (WordPress) for both game and movie reviews. We can then organize your posts, for example, by genre which humans will appreciate due to the added relevancy, and Search engines will appreciate because of the semantics.

With any luck, what would *normally* be a super long list is much more digestible afterwards. If you want to cut down further, we can also organize things by year. We see this sort of thing often.

Now you also hit that **"Best [things] in 2021"** keyword which enjoy consistently high organic search volume.

Obviously you can still do broader mixed lists (like we typically see with "Editor's Picks"); those can (and likely ought to be) be fairly lengthy.

### Re: GamesRadar Example

So GamesRadar is using pagination for this. I don't recommend that. Down the road it will lead to a convoluted architecture and cause indexing issues. I'd opt to use JavaScript instead if a multi-page experience is desired.

I think that this site does a nice job. They keep 1 page for their take on the current best PC games and keep it updated often (last was Nov 10 21). It's got about 25-30 games on the list.

[image: A screenshot of pcgamesn's article on the best pc games to play.]

They also offer a better UX by displaying all of the games with page jump links just after their introduction. This way we can ignore the stuff we don't care about and get to what we *do* faster.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions. Actually we did all the things you suggested. My question was for those best [things] in 2021. As not all of our best things posts not just top ten, they can be quite lengthy. So I was wondering should I do something like gamesradar+ did.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address gamesradar+ question

Comment: Thank you kindly for responding to my questions,